# How to know why my tomcat is killed by Kernal

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

I have my application running on Tomcat and after sometime I see that the process is killed by Kernal, I would like to know how to debug this issue.

I see below message in kern.log file at path /var/log:

```
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.480689] splunkd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.482610] splunkd cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.488425] CPU: 1 PID: 1619 Comm: splunkd Not tainted 3.19.0-42-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.488431] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 04/14/2014
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.488435]  0000000000000000 ffff8800bb9eb888 ffffffff817afcd5 00000000000087ee
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.488443]  ffff8802322475c0 ffff8800bb9eb928 ffffffff817aabb7 0000000000000000
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.488448]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.488455] Call Trace:
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489426]  [<ffffffff817afcd5>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489433]  [<ffffffff817aabb7>] dump_header+0x7f/0x1f1
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489900]  [<ffffffff81179b3b>] oom_kill_process+0x22b/0x390
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489908]  [<ffffffff8117a332>] out_of_memory+0x4d2/0x520
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489914]  [<ffffffff8117f720>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x940/0xa60
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489922]  [<ffffffff811c44b1>] alloc_pages_current+0x91/0x100
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489927]  [<ffffffff81176447>] __page_cache_alloc+0xa7/0xc0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489931]  [<ffffffff811787a8>] filemap_fault+0x1a8/0x430
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489937]  [<ffffffff811a14d9>] __do_fault+0x39/0x90
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.489941]  [<ffffffff811a3e67>] do_read_fault.isra.55+0x1d7/0x2f0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.490489]  [<ffffffff810998aa>] ? dequeue_task+0x5a/0x80
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.490498]  [<ffffffff811a5a24>] handle_mm_fault+0x604/0x10e0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.490520]  [<ffffffff810dd9e8>] ? hrtimer_try_to_cancel+0x48/0xe0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.490531]  [<ffffffff81061e84>] __do_page_fault+0x1c4/0x5b0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492741]  [<ffffffff81231511>] ? ep_poll+0x311/0x350
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492750]  [<ffffffff810a0b40>] ? wake_up_state+0x20/0x20
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492756]  [<ffffffff810622a1>] do_page_fault+0x31/0x70
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492764]  [<ffffffff817b9868>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492767] Mem-Info:
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492771] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492774] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492777] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492781] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492782] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492785] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  20
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492787] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 145
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492790] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  71
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.492791] Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493650] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493671] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493673] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493679] active_anon:1298444 inactive_anon:304238 isolated_anon:0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493679]  active_file:34 inactive_file:21 isolated_file:0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493679]  unevictable:0 dirty:5 writeback:0 unstable:0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493679]  free:22359 slab_reclaimable:3817 slab_unreclaimable:4113
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493679]  mapped:21 shmem:421 pagetables:4681 bounce:0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493679]  free_cma:0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493683] Node 0 DMA free:15900kB min:128kB low:160kB high:192kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:8kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493692] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2976 7966 7966
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493697] Node 0 DMA32 free:41900kB min:25196kB low:31492kB high:37792kB active_anon:1842924kB inactive_anon:538140kB active_file:84kB inactive_file:104kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3129280kB managed:3049516kB mlocked:0kB dirty:12kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:1668kB slab_reclaimable:3816kB slab_unreclaimable:4368kB kernel_stack:960kB pagetables:6072kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:30156 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493704] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 4990 4990
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493707] Node 0 Normal free:31636kB min:42252kB low:52812kB high:63376kB active_anon:3350852kB inactive_anon:678812kB active_file:52kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:5242880kB managed:5110660kB mlocked:0kB dirty:8kB writeback:0kB mapped:84kB shmem:16kB slab_reclaimable:11452kB slab_unreclaimable:12076kB kernel_stack:2448kB pagetables:12652kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:27348 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493713] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493717] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 1*8kB (U) 1*16kB (U) 2*32kB (U) 1*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (R) 3*4096kB (M) = 15900kB
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493731] Node 0 DMA32: 1832*4kB (UM) 1350*8kB (UM) 679*16kB (UEM) 248*32kB (UM) 78*64kB (UM) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 41920kB
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493743] Node 0 Normal: 7929*4kB (M) 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 31716kB
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493753] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493755] 152611 total pagecache pages
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493757] 152133 pages in swap cache
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493759] Swap cache stats: add 2429803, delete 2277670, find 32042376/32159653
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493763] Free swap  = 0kB
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493765] Total swap = 974844kB
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493767] 2097038 pages RAM
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493768] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493770] 53017 pages reserved
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493771] 0 pages cma reserved
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493774] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493776] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493801] [  468]     0   468     3820        3      14       53             0 upstart-file-br
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493806] [  501]   101   501    78605     3496      63     2172             0 rsyslogd
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493810] [  633]     0   633     3816       18      14       45             0 upstart-socket-
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493816] [  637]     0   637     4827       28      14       54             0 rpcbind
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493821] [  639]   102   639    24886       48      49      195             0 dbus-daemon
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493825] [  777]     0   777     2372        2      10       30             0 getty
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493831] [  782]     0   782     2372        2       9       29             0 getty
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493836] [  790]     0   790     2372        2      10       32             0 getty
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493840] [  793]     0   793     2372        2      11       30             0 getty
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.493848] [  795]     0   795     2372        2      10       32             0 getty
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494726] [  829]     0   829     3202        5      11       31             0 atd
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494732] [  831]     0   831     4331       26      14       32             0 cron
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494736] [  834]     0   834     1093        2       8       35             0 acpid
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494742] [  910]     0   910     4832       38      15       35             0 irqbalance
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494746] [  927]   103   927    82342       38      59      254             0 whoopsie
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494751] [  996]     0   996     2559       58      10      518             0 dhclient
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494755] [ 1083]     0  1083    19066       27      42      173             0 sshd
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494758] [ 1177]     0  1177    21359       85      39      131             0 vmtoolsd
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494762] [ 1290]   106  1290    22904       43      49      231             0 ntpd
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494765] [ 1359]     0  1359   207408      245      67      178             0 nscd
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494769] [ 1478]     0  1478     4979       29      15       42             0 master
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494773] [ 1491]   108  1491     5428       32      15       44             0 qmgr
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494776] [ 1619]     0  1619    52142     5651      93    14150             0 splunkd
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494780] [ 1620]     0  1620    14636        1      23     1735         -1000 splunkd
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494783] [ 1692]   100  1692     4911       63      12      210             0 nagios3
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494790] [ 1922]     0  1922     1901        2       9       28             0 getty
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494793] [ 2893]   100  2893     4424       15      11      105             0 nrpe
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494797] [ 3021]   999  3021    46156    20287      90     8730             0 gmond
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494803] [ 9911]     0  9911     4870        0      14       55             0 upstart-udev-br
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494812] [ 9914]     0  9914    10346        1      24      100         -1000 systemd-udevd
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494818] [10000]     0 10000     8809       36      22       45             0 systemd-logind
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494823] [10797]     0 10797    45843      272      62     1458             0 apache2
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494828] [ 9751]    33  9751    45865      360      57     1396             0 apache2
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494831] [ 9752]    33  9752    45956      390      58     1412             0 apache2
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494836] [ 9753]    33  9753    45865      361      57     1395             0 apache2
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494840] [ 9754]    33  9754    45867      363      57     1395             0 apache2
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494845] [ 9755]    33  9755    45865      362      57     1394             0 apache2
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494851] [ 2545]   100  2545     4460        0      13      128             0 nrpe
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494855] [ 3688]   108  3688     8582       41      22       97             0 tlsmgr
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494859] [ 3708]    33  3708    45956      393      58     1409             0 apache2
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494865] [ 3729]    33  3729    45861      361      57     1391             0 apache2
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494869] [13954]   107 13954  2084176  1418568    3304   211435             0 java
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494874] [30745]   108 30745     5389       50      15        0             0 pickup
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.494878] Out of memory: Kill process 13954 (java) score 713 or sacrifice child
Jun 24 03:40:48 test-host-name kernel: [4329150.509555] Killed process 13954 (java) total-vm:8336704kB, anon-rss:5674272kB, file-rss:0kB
```

From log it is clear that due to out of memory the kernal has killed the process. But I want to know how to debug this issue, are there any tools which can help me to find out what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How much memory do you reserve for Tomcat ?
Take a look at this page : http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/